# How can I get only the executable name after using GetModuleFileNameEx

Tags: c++, winapi, psapi

I want to store the executable name without the directory (i.e. system.exe).

How can I do this?

```
HANDLE Handle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS, 0, ProcessID);
if (GetModuleFileNameEx(Handle, 0, (LPWSTR)exename, sizeof(exename) - 1))
{
   ProcessName = (wchar*)exename; // I want to store only the executable name without "C:\\..."
}
```

Comment: Did you try parsing the string to get just the exe name?

Comment: i don't know how :) i am newbie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you search MSDN?
There you can find the functions [`PathFindFileName`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773589(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`PathFindExtension`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773587(v=vs.85).aspx) that you can utilize to build your file name.

Comment: thank you
but i am getting linking error
LNK2019 unresolved external symbol __imp__PathFindExtensionW@4 referenced in function _main Test

Comment: @Somethingelse: Right, so link the library. Its name is told to you right there on the documentation page. Shlwapi.lib.

Comment: The `MAX_PATH` length limitation of those shell utility functions is of limited utility. The [<filesystem>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh874694.aspx) implementation of Visual Studio 2015 and above may be a better match.